Add all the fields of "joinable tables" programmatically
I have two tables:
CREATE TABLE [instrument].[InstrumentType] (
    [InstrumentTypeId] INT           NOT NULL IDENTITY (1, 1),
    [Name]             VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_InstrumentType]   PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([InstrumentTypeId] ASC)
);

CREATE TABLE [instrument].[Instrument] (
    [InstrumentId]     INT            NOT NULL IDENTITY (1, 1),
    [InstrumentTypeId] INT            NOT NULL,
    [Name]             VARCHAR (255)  NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Instrument]                PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([InstrumentId] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Instrument_InstrumentType] FOREIGN KEY ([InstrumentTypeId]) REFERENCES [instrument].[InstrumentType] ([InstrumentTypeId])
);

I can simply fetch the instrument type without writing the join (fabulous feature):
create.select(INSTRUMENT.INSTRUMENTID, INSTRUMENT.NAME, INSTRUMENT.instrumenttype.NAME)
      .from(INSTRUMENT)
      .fetch()

I have many tables similar to this and I would like to create this query programmatically. I have tried using INSTRUMENT.references but the query fails because it refers to the IDENTIFIERTYPE table instead of using the INSTRUMENT.instrumenttype path. This is the query rendered by my fetch method:
select
  [instrument].[Instrument].[InstrumentId],
  [instrument].[Instrument].[Name],
  [instrument].[InstrumentType].[Name]
from [instrument].[Instrument]

This is what I have so far but I can't find the right way to go through the foreign key paths like in the manual query.
val T = INSTRUMENT

fun fetch(dsl: DSLContext): Any {
  return dsl
    .select(fieldList())
    .from(T)
    .fetch()
}

protected open fun fieldList(): Set<Field<*>> {
  val result = mutableSetOf<Field<*>>()
  val tables = fkTableList(T)
  for (t in tables) {
    val fk = t.references.flatMap { it.fields }.toSet()
    val include = t.fields().toSet()

    //Remove INSTRUMENTTYPEID
    val selectedFields = include - fk
    result.addAll(selectedFields)
  }
  return result
}

private fun fkTableList(table: Table<*>): List<Table<*>> {
  val result = mutableListOf(table)
  val fkTables = table.references.map { it.key.table }
  result.addAll(fkTables.flatMap { fkTableList(it) })
  return result
}


Note, there's this feature request to construct org.jooq.Path instances programmatically, which you might be interested in:

https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/15645

It hasn't been implemented yet as of jOOQ 3.19. Without using Path types, you'll have to explicitly add the join tree yourself. You can't just add the projection alone. A relatively simple way to do this would be to use the ON KEY synthetic join syntax (which jOOQ's Path implementation also uses internally):
.from(joinTree(T))

And then:
private fun joinTree(table: Table<*>): Table<*> {
  var result = table

  for (fk in table.references) {

    // Optionally, use inner join for non-nullable FKs
    result = result.leftJoin(joinTree(

      // Disambiguate tables that are joined many times through different paths
      fk.key.table.`as`(fk.name)
    )).onKey(fk)
  }

  return result
}

This recursion style produces right-associative join trees (i.e. A JOIN (B JOIN C) instead of A JOIN B JOIN C), which will avoid ambiguities in case a child table has multiple paths towards the same parent / ancestor. This is what jOOQ's implicit joins also do for the same reason.
Caveats

The solution assumes unique foreign key names. You can use other path aliasing approaches if that assumption doesn't hold
The recursion will never stop if you have cycles in your foreign key graph!


Works great thanks - once deep in the recursion, is it possible to know which table is table (i.e. the real table: INSTRUMENTTYPE, not the alias: FK_INSTRUMENT_INSTRUMENTTYPE)? I can see that table.alias.wrapped has the info but it's not public.

@assylias Check QOM.Aliasable.$aliased()

Just posted another version that gets the correct alias to be able to write record[INSTRUMENT.instrumenttype.NAME] and avoid ambiguous warnings (for deeply nested joins) - I hope you don't change the generator too much haha...

If anyone is interested, my final version of the method is:
private fun joinTree(table: Table<*>, fieldSet: MutableSet<Field<*>>, path: Table<*> = table): Table<*> {
  var result = table
  fieldSet.addAll(fieldSet(path))

  for (fk in table.references) {
    //We try to find the jooq XxxPath class that represents the join
    //We can then get the correct label and referring to any joined column in fetch { row -> row[PARENT.child1.child2.COLUMN] } should return the correct value
    val fkPath =  try {
      val cls = fk.key.table::class // for example: a.b.c.Instrument
      val pathClsName = cls.qualifiedName + "$" + cls.simpleName + "Path" // for example: a.b.c.Instrument$InstrumentPath
      val pathCls = Class.forName(pathClsName)
      val c = pathCls.constructors[0]
      c.newInstance(path, fk, null) as Table<*>
    } catch (e: ClassNotFoundException) {
      fk.key.table.`as`(Internal.createPathAlias(table, fk, null))
    }

    //We create a new table - if we use fkPath directly, automatic joins are added that break the query
    //(but we need fkPath to get the correct alias)
    val fkTable = fk.key.table.`as`(fkPath.name)

    fieldSet.addAll(fieldSet(fkTable))

    result = result.innerJoin(joinTree(fkTable, fieldSet, fkPath)).onKey(fk)
  }

  return result
}

